# Mysql Trigger Insert record into another table on specific column update

Tags: mysql, sql

Alright, I am trying to create a trigger in MySQL that will insert the old date in the table into another table to track the changes that occur. The following tables is what I have. I cannot change the users table but I can change the user_changes table. I created this trigger below but it keeps giving me an error on the line with the insert statement.

> users: id, StoreNbr, UserNbr, LvlNbr, Paid1, Paid2
>   user_changes: id, store_nbr, user_number, level_number, OldPaid1, OldPaid2, create

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS usersToChanges;
CREATE TRIGGER `usersToChanges` AFTER UPDATE ON users FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF LENGTH(CONV(NEW.Status, 10, 2)) NOT IN (5,6,8) AND (NOT(NEW.Paid1 <=> OLD.Paid1) OR NOT(NEW.Paid2 <=> OLD.Paid2)) 
    THEN
        INSERT INTO user_changes (store_nbr, user_number, level_number, OldPaid1, OldPaid2, created) 
        VALUES (OLD.StoreNbr, OLD.UserNbr, OLD.LvlNbr, OLD.Paid1, OLD.Paid2, NOW());
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: SQL SYNTAX ERROR on line six;

Comment: Are you running this in the mysql command line client, or in a GUI like phpMyAdmin, or from application code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [**DELIMTER command**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-programs-defining.html) to define procedural code:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS usersToChanges;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `usersToChanges` AFTER UPDATE ON users FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF LENGTH(CONV(NEW.Status, 10, 2)) NOT IN (5,6,8) AND (NOT(NEW.Paid1 <=> OLD.Paid1) OR NOT(NEW.Paid2 <=> OLD.Paid2)) 
    THEN
        INSERT INTO user_changes (store_nbr, user_number, level_number, OldPaid1, OldPaid2, created) 
        VALUES (OLD.StoreNbr, OLD.UserNbr, OLD.LvlNbr, OLD.Paid1, OLD.Paid2, NOW());
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

The semicolon usually delimits a single command, not procedural code. Notice how I changed the `END;` to `END $$` to finish making the trigger. Then, I switched back to the default delimiter of semicolon.

Comment: I get this error 'DELIMTER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `usersToChanges` AFTER UPDATE ON users FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN' at line 1